# Django - makemigrations - No changes detected

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I was trying to create migrations within an existing app using the makemigrations command but it outputs "No changes detected".

Usually I create new apps using the `startapp` command but did not use it for this app when I created it.

After debugging, I found that it is not creating a migration because the `migrations` package/folder is missing from an app.

Would it be better if it creates the folder if it is not there or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have your app added to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes it is in installed app, for the first time , better to be use `makemigrations <myapp>` as Alasdair pointed out also.

Comment: Remove         'abstract = True' :)

Comment: 'makemigrations' did not work. 'makemigrations <myapp>' worked

Comment: In my case the changes were not detected because the classes inside models.py did not inherit from models.Model. After making the classes inside the models.py inherit from models.Model e.g. MyDataClass(models.Model), the problem was solved. Trivial, but hope this might help someone.

Comment: make sure your app has an empty `__init__.py` file to let django know to include this app on load

Comment: I had the same issue, and it was because I forgot to register the model in `app/admin.py`.

Comment: Your linux(ubuntu) operating system change the owner of the project folder
#chown username -R <directory>

Comment: i was missing (models.Model) while creating the model.

Answer (score 547, accepted):

To create initial migrations for an app, run `makemigrations` and specify the app name. The migrations folder will be created.

```
./manage.py makemigrations <myapp>
```

Your app must be included in `INSTALLED_APPS` first (inside settings.py).

Comment: Any idea why they <sometimes> force us to specify the app ?

Comment: @maazza you need to specify the app name if the app does not have `migrations` folder. This could happen if you created the app manually, or you have upgraded from an older version of Django that didn't have migrations.

Comment: @maazza Actually you need a python package (with `__init__.py`) named 'migrations' in the app.

Comment: Sounds like something that Django should handle automatically.

Comment: @duality_ this [is by design](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps) - Django doesn't assume that you want migrations for your app. If it created migrations for all apps, it could lead to errors when you run `migrate`.

Comment: this issue cause me two days to debug,     and your answer simply solve my problem,   i just wrongly assume that makemigrations  will automatically applly to all installed app.

Comment: I faced similar issue; I had deleted the migrations folder, so if it happens to you check that you have a `migrations` folder with a file `__init__.py` in it.

Comment: This answer is the correct one, you might create a new sub app under the django app that you have created and you forget to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. Perhaps I have a project called `marketing` in my `settings.py` it would be something like.


```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "polymorphic",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "contacts",
]
```

Answer (score 107):

My problem (and so solution) was yet different from those described above.

I wasn't using `models.py` file, but created a `models` directory and created the `my_model.py` file there, where I put my model. Django couldn't find my model so it wrote that there are no migrations to apply.

My solution was: in the `my_app/models/__init__.py` file I added this line:
`from .my_model import MyModel`

Comment: This happended to be the solution for me as well, but I do not understand why this is. Does anyone have some insight as to what may be causing this?

Comment: Django has a default paths of where to look for your models. If the project structure is different, and the models are not in the usual place, they need to be imported there.

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė what if I need to remove such models?

Comment: @DaniilMashkin I imagine you would need to remove imports also. This is one of the ways of structuring your project (not the only one) and you have to deal with additional tasks that comes with it if you choose it :)

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė I removed all imports and models. When run `makemigration` I had no changes

Comment: That's weird. I haven't deleted the models. Maybe try making migrations only for one app, like so: `python manage.py makemigrations some_app`

Comment: I used the "classic" architecture for models, then I migrated to the "models folder" architecture, and any migration is still detected on my existing models. However, now, when creating a *new* model, I have this issue. Your solution works well, but it let my codebase kind of inconsistent because sometimes there is an import, sometimes not. Maybe there is a better solution. I guess Django should propose a settings with a list of folders to look for when trying to find new models.

Answer (score 95):

There are multiple possible reasons for django not detecting what to migrate during the `makemigrations` command.

1. **migration folder** You need a migrations package in your app.
2. **INSTALLED_APPS** You need your app to be specified in the `INSTALLED_APPS` .dict
3. **Verbosity**  start by running `makemigrations -v 3` for verbosity. This might shed some light on the problem.
4. **Full path** In `INSTALLED_APPS` it is recommended to specify the full module app config path 'apply.apps.MyAppConfig'
5. **--settings** you might want to make sure the correct settings file is set: `manage.py makemigrations --settings mysite.settings`
6. **specify app name** explicitly put the app name in *`manage.py makemigrations myapp`* - that narrows down the migrations for the app alone and helps you isolate the problem.
7. **model meta** check you have the right `app_label` in your model meta
8. **Debug django** debug django core script. makemigrations command is pretty much straight forward. [Here's how to do it in pycharm](https://djangotricks.blogspot.co.il/2016/05/debugging-management-commands-in-pycharm.html). change your script definition accordingly (ex: `makemigrations --traceback myapp`)

#### Multiple databases:

- **Db Router** when working with django db router, the router class (your custom router class) needs to implement the `allow_syncdb` method.

> makemigrations always creates migrations for model changes, but if
>   allow_migrate() returns False,

Comment: Covered many scenarios regarding the problem, should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Another possibility: The wrong name is being imported, i.e. importing a field from forms instead of fields, or importing a model from forms instead of models. An example: `from recurrence.forms import RecurrenceField` but it should have been `from recurrence.fields import RecurrenceField`.

Comment: One more reason. Make sure that the model is used within a route for the website (via admin or otherwise). "The `makemigrations` script looks for models which are connected from `urls.py`". Found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093651/django-migrations-not-detecting-all-changes

Comment: cmd example: `python manage.py makemigrations  -v 3 <app_name>`

Comment: When I add a table, and then add a Foreign Key reference this new table at same time. 
It has to be divided to 2 steps: 
pre step: add INSTALLED_APPS to settings. 
1) create new table: python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> ;
2) add Foreign Key: python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: @user1134422 this is one of the best answers on all of StackOverflow to any question.  It answers lots of people's problems tracing to the same appearance.  Thank you.

Comment: I went through all points but it still wasn't working for me. Turns out, the superclass models.Model was missing from the data model class in models.py . Check that too!

Comment: If the above list doesn't help try mentally following your code through the documented start up process and see if that gives you any clues. It's not quite as bad as you think; better than spening all day with no migrations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded

This is why magic is bad. Magic is supposed to hide the implementation details that you don't need to know, but with Django every time you do something interesting you need to dig inside the magic. It's not Pythonic. One day, there will be no Django. Django is not forever.

Comment: Make sure your model is imported somewhere else in your project...

Answer (score 36):

I've read many answers to this question often stating to simply run `makemigrations` in some other ways. But to me, the problem was in the `Meta` subclass of models.

I have an app config that says `label = <app name>` (in the `apps.py` file, beside `models.py`, `views.py` etc). If by any chance your meta class doesn't have the same label as the app label (for instance because you are splitting one too big app into multiple ones), no changes are detected (and no helpful error message whatsoever). So in my model class I have now:

```
class ModelClassName(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = '<app name>' # <-- this label was wrong before.

    field_name = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

Running Django 1.10 here.

Comment: What happens if you don't have a `Meta` at all? What value does it assume for `app_label` then as a default?

Answer (score 28):

Another thing that will cause this is a trailing comma after the field which will cause the field to skipped during makemigrations:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)  # works
    language_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='en')  # works
    is_dumb = models.BooleanField(default=False),  # doesn't work
```

I had a trailing `,` in one line perhaps from copy&paste. The line with `is_dumb` doesn't create a model migration with `./manage.py makemigrations` because Python thinks it is a tuple, and Django doesn't consider it a field.

Comment: The trailing comma can cause bugs elsewhere as well; the comma makes the statement a tuple, so `is_dumb` is equal to `(models.BooleanField(default=False), )` which `makemigrations` doesn't know how to convert into a database column.

Comment: this happened to me,  should be a warning if it doesn't know what to do

Comment: Genius!! worked for me

Answer (score 25):

**update**: One should make sure that an `__init__.py` file exists in the `migrations` folder before trying:

`./manage.py makemigrations <myapp1> <myapp2> ... <myappN>`

---

There are sometimes when `./manage.py makemigrations` is superior to `./manage.py makemigrations <myapp>` because it can handle certain conflicts between apps.

Those occasions occur silently and it takes several hours of `swearing` to understand the real meaning of the dreaded `No changes detected` message.

Therefore, it is a far better choice to make use of the following command:

`./manage.py makemigrations <myapp1> <myapp2> ... <myappN>`

Comment: 4 hours of debugging and THIS was the problem! Had __init__.py added to .gitignore. File was there locally, so everything worked. When I pushed to Heroku, that app's migrations were ignored! This fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

It is a comment but should probably be an answer.

Make sure that your app name is in settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS` otherwise no matter what you do it will not run the migrations.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog',
]
```

Then run:

```
./manage.py makemigrations blog
```

Comment: but it creates the table name as 'appname_modelname', when we run 'manage.py migrate' command

Comment: See [model meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#db-table) to change the table name

Answer (score 14):

**Method : 1**

*Step : 1*

Make sure your app must be included in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

*Stpe : 2*

```
python manage.py makemigrations <appname>
```

if same message shows (No changes detected)

**!Warning This is Very Risky For Your Project So Make Sure You Have Backup For Your Project Before Applying The Method 2.**

**Method 2**

rename your app name and make new app using :

```
django-admin startapp <appname>
```

copy all `.py` files `except` from the old app

- migration folder
- **pycache** folder
- **init**.py
- test.py file if you didn't wrote code in it

and paste into the new app which you made recently

remember you have to make exact the same name for new app otherwise you have to make more changes in the project.

Answer (score 11):

I had copied a table in from outside of django and the Meta class defaulted to "managed = false". For example:

```
class Rssemailsubscription(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36)
    ...
    area = models.FloatField('Area (Sq. KM)', null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'RSSEmailSubscription'
```

By changing `managed` to `True`, `makemigrations` started picking up changes.

Answer (score 11):

1. Make sure your app is mentioned in installed_apps in settings.py
2. Make sure you model class extends models.Model

Answer (score 11):

My problem was much simpler than the above answers and probably a far more common reason as long as your project is already set up and working.  In one of my applications that had been working for a long time, migrations seemed wonky, so in a hurry, I did the following:

```
rm -r */migrations/*
rm db.sqlite3
python3 manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

Whaat??

I had mistakenly also removed all the `__init__.py` files :( - Everything was working again after I went in and:

```
touch ads1/migrations/__init__.py
```

For each of my applications then the `makemigrations` worked again.

It turns out that I had manually created a new application by copying another and forgot to put the `__init__.py` in the `migrations` folder and that confinved me that everything was wonky - leading my making it worse with an `rm -r` as described above.

Hope this helps someone from swearing at the "No changes detected" error for a few hours.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible reason is if you had some models defined in another file (not in a package) and haven't referenced that anywhere else.

For me, simply adding `from .graph_model import *` to `admin.py` (where `graph_model.py` was the new file) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

When adding new models to the django api application and running the `python manage.py makemigrations` the tool did not detect any new models.

The strange thing was that the old models did got picked by `makemigrations`, but this was because they were referenced in the `urlpatterns` chain and the tool somehow detected them. So keep an eye on that behavior.

The problem was because the directory structure corresponding to the models package had subpackages and all the `__init__.py` files were empty. They must explicitly import all the required classes in **each subfolder and in the models** `__init__.py` for Django to pick them up with the `makemigrations` tool.

```
models
  ├── __init__.py          <--- empty
  ├── patient
  │   ├── __init__.py      <--- empty
  │   ├── breed.py
  │   └── ...
  ├── timeline
  │   ├── __init__.py      <-- empty
  │   ├── event.py
  │   └── ...
```

Answer (score 5):

This might hopefully help someone else, as I ended up spending hours trying to chase this down.

**If** you have a function *within* your model by the same name, this will remove the value. Pretty obvious in hindsight, but nonetheless.

So, if you have something like this:

```
class Foobar(models.Model):
    [...]
    something = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    [...]
    def something(self):
        return [some logic]
```

In that case, the function will override the setting above, making it "invisible" to `makemigrations`.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
```

make sure 'blog.apps.BlogConfig', (this is included in your settings.py in order to make your app migrations)

then run python3 manage.py makemigrations blog or your app name

Answer (score 3):

A very dumb issue you can have as well is to define two `class Meta` in your model. In that case, any change to the first one won't be applied when running `makemigrations`.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    someotherfield = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=["somefield"], name="somefield_idx")]

    def somefunc(self):
        pass

    # Many lines...

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=["someotherfield"], name="someotherfield_idx")]
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case i forgot to insert the class arguments

Wrong:

```
class AccountInformation():
```

Correct

```
class AccountInformation(models.Model):
```

Comment: This worked for me. I think this one depends on the python version.

Answer (score 3):

I had a different issue while creating a new app called `deals`. I wanted to separate the models inside that app so I had 2 model files named `deals.py` and `dealers.py`.
When running `python manage.py makemigrations` I got: `No changes detected`.

I went ahead and inside the `__init__.py` which lives on the same directory where my model files lived (deals and dealer) I did

```
from .deals import *
from .dealers import *
```

And then the `makemigrations` command worked.

Turns out that if you are not importing the models anywhere OR your models file name isn't `models.py` then the models wont be detected.

Another issue that happened to me is the way I wrote the app in `settings.py`:

I had:

```
apps.deals
```

It should've been including the root project folder:

```
cars.apps.deals
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved that problem by doing this:

1. Erase the "db.sqlite3" file. **The issue** here is that your current data base will be erased, so you will have to remake it again.
2. Inside the migrations folder of your edited app, erase the last   updated file. Remember that the first created file is: "0001_initial.py". For example: I made a new class and register it by the "makemigrations" and "migrate" procedure, now a new file called "0002_auto_etc.py" was created; erase it.
3. Go to the "*pycache*" folder (inside the migrations folder) and erase the file "0002_auto_etc.pyc".
4. Finally, go to the console and use "python manage.py makemigrations" and "python manage.py migrate".

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I fought with this same issue all day and my solution was a simple one.

I had my directory structure something along the lines of...

```
apps/
   app/
      __init__.py
      app_sub1/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app_sub2/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app_sub3/
           __init__.py
           models.py
   app2/
      __init__.py
      app2_sub1/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app2_sub2/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app2_sub3/
           __init__.py
           models.py
    main_app/
      __init__.py
      models.py
```

And since all the other models up until the one I had a problem with were being imported somewhere else that ended up importing from `main_app` which was registered in the `INSTALLED_APPS`, I just got lucky that they all worked.

But since I only added each `app` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and not the `app_sub*` when I finally added a new models file that wasn't imported ANYWHERE else, Django totally ignored it.

My fix was adding a `models.py` file to the base directory of each `app` like this...

```
apps/
   app/
      __init__.py
      models.py <<<<<<<<<<--------------------------
      app_sub1/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app_sub2/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app_sub3/
           __init__.py
           models.py
   app2/
      __init__.py
      models.py <<<<<<<<<<--------------------------
      app2_sub1/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app2_sub2/
           __init__.py
           models.py
      app2_sub3/
           __init__.py
           models.py
    main_app/
      __init__.py
      models.py
```

and then add `from apps.app.app_sub1 import *` and so on to each of the `app` level `models.py` files.

Bleh... this took me SO long to figure out and I couldn't find the solution anywhere... I even went to page 2 of the google results.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to put correct arguments:

```
class LineInOffice(models.Model):   # here
    addressOfOffice = models.CharField("Корхоная жош",max_length= 200)   #and here
    ...
```

in models.py
and then it started to drop that annoying

**No changes detected in app 'myApp '**

Answer (score 2):

This could be done by using two steps that are mentioned below.

1. add your **app** to `settings.py` > **INSTALLED_APPS**
2. open admin.py

```
from .models import upImg
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(upImg)
```

NOTE: replace `upImg` with your className defined in `models.py`

after that see if there still any `python manage.py makemigrations` are left or not. if there is, than execute `python manage.py migrate` too.

For more info follow this [django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site#registering_models).

Answer (score 2):

Its easy, you need to add empty **init**.py in empty migrations folder.
Then check migrations using "python manage.py makemigrations"

Directory structure-

- Your App

  - migrations

    - **init**.py

Comment: This should be `__init__.py`, not 'init.py' as the author suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is you have to include your app in INSTALLED_APPS.

I missed it and I found this same issue.

after specifying my app name migration became successful

```html
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'boards',
]
```

please note I mentioned boards in last, which is my app name.

Answer (score 1):

One more edge case and solution:

I added a boolean field, and at the same time added an @property referencing it, with the same name (doh). Commented the property and migration sees and adds the new field. Renamed the property and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering your model in admin.py, here's an example:-
admin.site.register(YourModelHere)

You can do the following things:-
 1. admin.site.register(YourModelHere) # In admin.py 
 2. Reload the page and try again
 3. Hit CTRL-S and save
 4. There might be an error, specially check models.py and admin.py
 5. Or, at the end of it all just restart the server

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with django 3.0, according migrations section in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/), running this was enough to update my table structure:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

But the output was always the same: 'no change detected' about my models after I executed 'makemigrations' script.
I had a syntax error on models.py at the model I wanted to update on db:

```
field_model : models.CharField(max_length=255, ...)
```

instead of:

```
field_model = models.CharField(max_length=255, ...)
```

Solving this stupid mistake, with those command the migration was done without problems. Maybe this helps someone.

Comment: I feel like Django should give more warning when you've got a messed up model. This fixed my issue too.

Answer (score 1):

My problem with this error, was that I had included:

```
class Meta:
   abstract = True
```

Inside model that I wanted to creation migrate for.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `polls.apps.PollsConfig` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `setting.py`

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason could be deletion of the existing db file and migrations folder
you can use python `manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` this should work. I once faced a similar problem.

Comment: if after deleting existing db file, it has not worked, you can try deleting migrations folder in app folder then 'manage.py makemigrations'

it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `managed = True` in yout model Meta, you need to remove it and do a migration. Then run the migrations again, it will detect the new updates.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Thing You can do is, Delete the existing database. In my case, I were using phpMyAdmin SQL database, so I manually delete the created database overthere.

**After Deleting:**
I create database in PhpMyAdmin, and doesn,t add any tables.

Again run the following Commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

**After These Commands**:  You can see django has automatically created other necessary tables in Database(Approx there are 10 tables).

`python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`

`python manage.py migrate`

**And Lastly:** After above commands all the model(table) you have created are directly imported to the database.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is you squashed some migrations and applied the resulting one, but forgot to remove the `replaces` attribute from it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a property with the same name as the field I have tried to add with `makemigrations`.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of many correct answers here, I yet have to add a new one as mine was a whole different thing that resulted in the same issue.

My problem was that in my models file I had my class model defined like:

`class JobAd:`
and had forgotten to actually do it like this:

`class JobAd(models.Model):`

Make sure you did not do the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, **you did not forget to inherit your class from models.Model?**

-> it should be like this

```
MyModelClass(models.Model):
   ... rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

python manage.py makemigrations  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share my case as well. My app name and level are different in app.py file. Once I start using level, it worked.

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations {app_level}
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I made is that I used `django-admin startapp <appname>` instead of `python manage.py startapp <appname>`. Although both of the commands yield similar results, the second approach helps to configure your newly created app with appropriate project-related settings. In addition to this, you may need to add your appname in the `INSTALLED_APPS` dict of your `settings.py file`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, make sure your app is registered in the Installed_app in the setting.py 
Then the above answer works perfectly fine

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm sure that you didn't set the models yet, so what dose it migrate now ??

So the solution is setting all variables and set Charfield, Textfield....... and migrate them and it will work.