# Django migrations not detecting all changes

Tags: python, django, migration

I have the following models. 
`BaseClass1` and `BaseClass2` are abstract models used by models.

In this case, the model `AdBreak` is used by a viewset and a serializer.
When I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, the changes on `AdBreak` model is detected. The model `AdBreakStatus` is not getting created.

Since, `AdBreakStatus` is linked to `AdBreak`, I am expecting a migration for `AdBreakStatus` also. Is my understanding wrong?

**Edit**

> In the initial state, there was only AdBreak and BaseClass1 model. The new state, AdBreakStatus and BaseClass2 models were added. Some of the fields from AdBreak were moved to AdBreakStatus.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
class BaseClass1(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class BaseClass2(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
    other_field = models.IntegerField()

class AdBreak(BaseClass1):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "ad_break"
    ad_break_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ... # Other fields

class AdBreakStatus(BaseClass2):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "ad_break_status"
    ad_break = models.ForeignKey(AdBreak)
    ... # Other Fields
```

Comment: A database migration transforms the database from one state to another. You have only shown us a single state; without knowing how your models (or tables) looked before this can't be answered.

Comment: In the initial state, there was only AdBreak and BaseClass1 model. 
The new state, AdBreakStatus and BaseClass2 models were added.
Some of the fields from AdBreak were moved to AdBreakStatus.

Comment: @Chris : If I add a viewset which points to `AdBreakStatus`, migration is detected. Any other way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I solved it in multiple ways.

#### Solution 1

There is a serializer `AdBreakSerializer` which serializes the model `AdBreak`.
Import `AdBreakStatus` model into the `AdBreakSerializer` file. 
Now `AdBreakStatus` model is detected and migrated.

> Problem in this approach is that, the import is not used, and hence will not follow the standards.

#### Solution 2

Write the `AdBreakStatus` model class inside the same file of `AdBreak`. This will also solve the problem.

---

## Finding / Understanding

The `makemigrations` script looks for models which are connected from `urls.py`. The script navigates from `urls.py` to all the viewset, then the corresponding serializers and models.

> All the models which needs to be migrated should come in the path of this traversal. **OR** Only those models which are traversed in this manner will be migrated.

Comment: Your findings are true, but they're just a side effect of the way Django work (in fact this wasn't true until the URL system checks were added that import your `urls.py`). Django explicitly imports the `models` submodule of every app in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you want a model to be loaded, make sure to import it into `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`. That way you are not depending on any import chains that might change over the course of your application's development. It also provides a convenient place to access your models in one place, even if they are defined in several files.

Answer (score 3):

Do this first:

```
python manage.py makemigrations 'your-app'
python manage.py migrate
```

If the above fails to detect changes, remove migration folder, open your database and open table django_migrations. You will see migrations listed associated to your app, delete the records and now execute makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: This solution is good when the app is in beta / initial development. Not good for later stages of the app.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone does the same mistake as me, in my case it was because the field I added had the same name as an existing property. So make sure that the field name is not already used.

Answer (score -1):

delete the migrations folder and sqlite file.  then run

```
python manage.py makemigrations 'app_name'
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This solution is good when the app is in beta / initial development. Not good for later stages of the app