# I keep getting no changes detected when migrating app in Django

Tags: python, django

I am following this video tutorial to learn Django: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t=909s

I am at the "Your first app component" section where he creates an app and then migrates it. I have followed every one of his steps so far yet I keep getting the no changes detected error when I migrate the app

I have tried researching ways to fix this but it doesn't seem like there is any one right way to do it, it's more of a case by case basis. I've made sure my app is under the install_apps section in the settings. I've tried python manage.py makemigrations but that tells me there are no changes detected. I've tried "python manage.py makemigrations product" to be more specific but it tells me that App 'product' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?" even though it is in installed apps

currently this is my installed apps section:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'product',
```

Comment: Please show the layout of your project files. In the video you linked to, the app name is `products` with an 's', so they would add `'products'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and run `manage.py makemigrations products`.

Comment: @Alasdair I tried adding the 's' at the end but I got the same result. This is what is inside the products folder on my laptop:                                                                                                     views.py
tests.py
models.py
migrations
apps.py
admin.py
__init__.py

Comment: If the folder name, `INSTALLED_APPS` and `makemigrations` command match, then it should work. You haven’t shown any code that would explain the issue you are seeing, so it’s difficult to help. Perhaps the migrations have already been created (run `manage.py showmigrations` to check).

Comment: @Alasdair I figured it out. The way I had my files organized there was something that wasn't where it should have been and that threw everything off. Once I put it in the proper place everything worked fine. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: This is a link to the same question with much more comprehensive coverage. Please try it if you want more guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49427361/134044

Answer (score 2):

after migrate and makemigrations command put your app name 
like this

```
python manage.py migrate product
python manage.py makemigrations product
```

my case it's working

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your app name in 'Installed_Apps' in settings.py. Add this first and then run again.

Answer (score 0):

for a proper migrations with 'python manage.py makemigrations' make sure that after creating your model class you save them before you typing any console code very important