# Running "migrate" won't produce migrations folder

Tags: django

As the title says running `python manage.py migrate` runs the migrations but no migrations directory is produced in the app directory hence no tables from `models.py` exist.

```
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

This is quite new error to me. What should I do ?

Comment: This is not an error. It just says what migrations it has applied. You first need to `makemigration` to generate the migration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that you have `migrations` directory with an empty `__init__.py` file in it. then add your app name (or app address) in INSTALLED_APP (in settings.py) then use `python manage.py makemigrations` to make migration files.

Now you can use migration command!

Comment: As advised, I created `migrations` directory with init file in it and it works now. Bless you buddy !

Answer (score 3):

`python manage.py migrate` only runs the existing migrations, it does not make new ones. What you're looking for is probably `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations` gives me nothing:  `No changes detected`.

Comment: If you get `No changes detected`, then use `python manage.py makemigrations yourapp` to create initial migrations for your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-makemigrations-no-changes-detected/36154224#36154224

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
python manage.py migrate 'yourappname'
```

Or:

```
python manage.py makemigrations 'yourappname'
```