# I accidentally deleted the migrations folder in Django

Tags: django

I am using Django, and Postgre for the DB. So I was done with all the migrations, but then I accidentally deleted the migrations folder in my editor. So I did the 'python manage.py makemigrations' again in the terminal, hoping I can get the folder back, but it replied 'No changes detected.' What should I do to get the folder back? Is it wrong to just simply make migrations again?
I've tried creating a new database and re-do the same process, but it still says 'No changes detected.'

I very much appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: @kamilyrb I use Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you try select file tree and press ctrl + z

Comment: FWIW, that's what you use a *version control system* for, and secondarily computer backups…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-makemigrations-no-changes-detected

Answer (score 14):

If you have deleted all migrations then you have to reset the migrations and create again. don't worry, your DB will be safe.
Follow the below steps if you want to fix the migrations without loosing the database.

**First Clear database migration history.**

a. go to python shell `python manage.py shell`

b. type `from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder`

c. type `MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.all().delete()`

**Second, recreate migrations**

Create a new folder `migrations`.
Create a file named `__init__.py` inside the folder.

Run command `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Apply fake migration so your database schema and migration history sync.

`python manage.py migrate --fake`

Comment: Did the steps, still getting the same results as last time.

Comment: I'm getting "No changes detected"

Comment: Have you checked that your django_migrations table is empty ?>

Comment: I found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-makemigrations-no-changes-detected

Comment: This is magic worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

I now found the solution on [Django - makemigrations - No changes detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-makemigrations-no-changes-detected)

The solution was:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations yourAppName
```

This is for **macOS**.

If you use **Windows** it's probably

```
py manage.py makemigrations yourAppName
```

and "yourAppName" should be the name of your app, not the same as in the example, only if your apps name is actually "yourAppName", then of course that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this recipe (Scenario 2, to keep the existing development DB)](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html)  works well. It can be applied to a single app, which is possibly trickier than resetting migrations on all apps at once.

Comment: Didn't work. Getting "No changes detected", every time. I tried different Scenarios. The one where you delete "db.sqlite3", I do not recommend to use, unless you have no problem creating a new superuser, because it will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

(if not in production and afford to loose data)

1. Simply delete the migration Folder from your app directory, delete *.sqlite3 file
2. python manage.py makemigrations
3. python manage.py migrate

You will get a new database file and with fixed migration.

Happy Django user !!

Answer (score -1):

Try these following steps:

1. clear pyc cache: run `python manage.py clear_pyc`
2. Create new migrations folder if the old one is deleted and create an `__init__.py` file inside
3. Create the migrations again by running `python manage.py makemigrations <your-app-name>`

Like that you will recover the deleted migration, as you can migrate afterwards everything by running `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score -2):

Delete everything under the migrations folder

and type the following command

`python manage.py makemigrations`