# makemigrations shows No changes detected

Tags: python, django

I totally beginner in django. I create one model which is in **models folder**
and run **python manage.py makemigrations** still its show **No changes detected**

[image]

> product.py

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/")
```

> **init**.py (models/**init**.py)

from .product import Product

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to run one more command -- python manage.py migrate

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>` Does this work?

Comment: No it's not working 
it's shows No migrations to apply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - makemigrations - No changes detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-makemigrations-no-changes-detected)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat my application name is a store but it shows No installed app with label 'store'.

Comment: @DharmendraKakde You have not added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings

Comment: Did you register your model in `admin.py`?

Comment: @Vaibhav no, shall I add?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat

here is **settings.py** file

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]`

Comment: Yeah. You've to do that. Add `admin.site.register({model-name})` to `admin.py` and then make migrations and migrate. Don't forget to import your model to `admin.py`

Comment: @DharmendraKakde As I said you have not added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the list add an entry `'<app_name>'`.

Comment: What is your app name?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat
Finally, your solution has worked.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Vaibhav

Thank you for your suggestions. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the database with `python manage.py migrate`.
If you have already created your models before doing this step there is no need to do `makemigrations`.
You have to use makemigrations only to collect the new changes and next apply this changes with `python manage.py migrate`.

1. Create initialize your DB with `python manage.py migrate`.
2. If there are changes collect them with `python manage.py makemigrations`.
3. Apply changes to the DB with  `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: I already initialize DB and admin panel working well. But I need to create another module which is `product`.
When I run `python manage.py makemigrations`
it shows `No changes detected`

Comment: No need to `initialize` the db before `makemigrations`, would in fact be troublesome if you are using a Custom User model.

Comment: Is your app in the INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file?

Comment: @B.Sebastiano
As I checked the settings.py file but I didn't get my application name

Comment: I suggest you to check this docs [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/). Try to check your folder structure.

Comment: @B.Sebastiano

Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope you solved the problem.