# How do I add another field to my model without getting an error?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added another field to my `Listing()` model called `highest_bid`. However, when I try to look at the listing model in the `/admin` page I get the `OperationalError`:
`no such column: auctions_listing.highest_bid`

After adding this field I tried using `makemigrations`, but it said that there were no changes and I also tried using `migrate` but that also said that there was nothing to migrate.

I also tried removing `null=True` on the field but that did not change anything.

How do I add this field without getting an error?

models.py:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    ...
    highest_bid = models.FloatField()
    # highest_bid = models.FloatField(null=True)
    # they both returned the same error
```

Comment: Can you please error trace to the questions? So that we can see what is going wrong there.

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want me to show?

Comment: I mean you should update the complete error from your terminal to the question and save it. So that any one can  see the error and answer you.

Comment: How do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-makemigrations-no-changes-detected) you have to make sure you:

1. Add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py`, otherwise `makemigrations` will not check for changes in your models
2. Run `./manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` if your app doesn't have a `migrations` module yet (i.e. it's going to be your app's `0001_initial.py` migration)

If you can cross these two requirements off your list (i.e. you're doing subsequent changes to your models), then `./manage.py makemigrations` without any `<app_name>` should simply work.

Answer (score 0):

how `makemigrations` didn't add the changes, you have to find a way to implement make migrations and create a file in the migrations folder otherwise, your field will not be in the DB and you will keep seeing the same error
so try `./manage.py makemigrations your_app_name`

Comment: I found a way to add the changes but got the error `django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency auctions.0001_initial on database 'default'.` instead.