# I created a new model and registered it to admin.py but when I am running python manage.py makemigrations it showing that no migrations to apply

Tags: python, django, django-models

**In models.py:**

```py
# from email.policy import default
# from pyexpat import model
from django.db import models
# from unicodedata import decimal
from shortuuid.django_fields import ShortUUIDField
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from userauths.models import CustomUser
from colorfield.fields import ColorField



STATUS_CHOICE=(
    ("process","Processing"),
    ("shipped","Shipped"),
    ("delevered","Delevered"),
)



STATUS=(
    ("draft","Draft"),
    ("disable","Disable"),
    ("rejected","Rejected"),
    ("In_review","In Review"),
    ("published","Published"),
)


RATING=(
    (1,"⭐☆☆☆☆"),
    (2,"⭐⭐☆☆☆"),
    (3,"⭐⭐⭐☆☆"),
    (4,"⭐⭐⭐⭐☆"),
    (5,"⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐"),
)
# Create your models here.

def user_directory_path(instance,filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


class Category(models.Model):
    cid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="cat",alphabet="abcdef")
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Food")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="category",default="category.jpg")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Categories"

    def catagory_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image.url))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Tags(models.Model):
    pass

class colour(models.Model):
    color=ColorField(format="hexa")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    vid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="ven",alphabet="abcdef")


    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Nest")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,default="vendor.jpg")
    description=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,default="Normal Vendorco")


    address=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="6,Dum Dum Road")
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="+91")
    chat_resp_time=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    shipping_on_time=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    authenticate_rating=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    days_return=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    warranty_period=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")


    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Vendors"

    def Vendor_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image.url))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    pid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="prd",alphabet="abcdef")


    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    cagtegory=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    # color=ColorField(format="hexa")


    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Apple")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,default="product.jpg")
    description=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,default="This is a product")

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1.99)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=2.99)

    specifications=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # tags=models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)

    product_status=models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=10,default="In_review")


    status=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    in_stock=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    digital=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    sku=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="sku",alphabet="abcdef")

    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Products"

    def product_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image.url))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_percentage(self):
        new_price=(self.price/self.old_price) * 100
        return new_price

class ProductImages(models.Model):
    images=models.ImageField(upload_to="product-image",default="product.jpg")
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Product Images"



######################################################Care,Order,CartItemsand Address###########################

class CartOrder(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default="1.99")
    paid_status=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    product_status=models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICE, max_length=30,default="prodcessing")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Cart Order"

class CartOrderItems(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey(CartOrder,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_num = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    product_status=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qty=models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default="15")
    total= models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default="20")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Cart Order Items"

    def oder_img(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="/media/%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image))


###########################Product Revew, wishlist, Address############################################

class ProductReview(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    review=models.TextField()
    rating = models.BigIntegerField(choices=RATING, default=3)

    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Product Reviews"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title

    def get_rating(self):
        return self.rating



class wishlist(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="wishlists"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title



class Address(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Address"
```

**In admin.py:**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from core.models import *

# Register your models here.


class ProductImagesAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model= ProductImages

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[ProductImagesAdmin]
    list_display=['user','title','product_image','price','featured','product_status']

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['title','catagory_image']

class VendorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['title','Vendor_image']

class CartOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','price','paid_status','order_date','product_status']

class CartOrderItemsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['order','invoice_num','product_status','item','image','qty','price','total']

class ProductReviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','product','review','rating','date']

class wishlistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','product','date']

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','address','status']

admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category,CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Vendor,VendorAdmin)
admin.site.register(CartOrder,CartOrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(CartOrderItems,CartOrderItemsAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProductReview,ProductReviewAdmin)
admin.site.register(wishlist,wishlistAdmin)
admin.site.register(Address,AddressAdmin)
admin.site.register(colour)
```

**When I am running python manage.py makemigrations it says:**

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'userauths' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
No changes detected
```

**And when I am running python manage.py migrate it says:**

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'userauths' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
```

Now When I am going to admin pannel there is a table called colour but when I am clicking it there is an

```
no such table: core_colour
```

error
**IN settings.py:**

```py
"""
Django settings for ecomprj project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-^mlg-*n8+um7^s$ivuodjy$sma!&ilikxhs^!t69k#&kuj-$gd'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jazzmin',
    'colorfield',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Custom Apps
    # 'core',
    'userauths'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecomprj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecomprj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]

MEDIA_URL='/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


JAZZMIN_SETTINGS={
    'site_header':"Sagarmoy Shop",
    'site_brand':"Sagarmoy Shop",
    'site_logo':"assets/images/logo/logo1.jpg",
    'site_copyright':"Sagarmoy Shop.com"
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userauths.CustomUser'
```

See in settings.py I Installed core app. Even my other models are working properly.
**python manage.py migrate error:**

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'userauths' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, core, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying core.0003_delete_colour...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: core_colour

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\Desktop\django ecom web\ecomprj\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\Desktop\django ecom web\ecomprj\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 356, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 132, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 389, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.delete_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 276, in delete_model
    super().delete_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 521, in delete_model
    self.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 201, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sagarmoy Sadhukhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: core_colour
```

Comment: Did you add `core` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes I add core to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Well it looks not, since it is not included in "apply all migrations". Can you share the `settings.py`?

Comment: I edited settings.py in questions please check it out

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: Add a [example]. Share the code contained in the `colorfield.fields` module. Which module does `models.py` and `admin.py` belong to? Add your project structure. Share enough information to enable us help you.

Comment: Ok I edited those things please check it out

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912173/django-1-7-makemigrations-not-detecting-changes/46362750#46362750) on the duplicate target

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> that worked but when I am running python manage.py migrate there is an error. I edited the error in the questions please check it out

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> that worked but when I am running python manage.py migrate there is an error. I edited the error in the questions please check it out

Comment: please help me out

Answer (score 0):

As willeM points out your app needs to be specified within INSTALLED_APPS (which is in settings.py), for it be taken into account for migrations and other configurations. Additionally to that there needs to be a __init__.py file within your app directory's migrations directory. And if you don't have a migrations directory inside your app directory altogether you can use

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

to create said files. You can check another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153748/django-makemigrations-no-changes-detected).

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> that worked but when I am running python manage.py migrate there is an error. I edited the error in the questions please check it out

Comment: As I understand from the error, its trying to migrate a table deletion while the table doesn't exist at the SQL side. You can go for a fake migration with `python manage.py migrate --FAKE` to stabilize or you can remove the core.0003_delete_colour... migration file so it doesn't try to delete a table that doesn't exist, than create the table with another migration and then delete it.